# cant insert data via post method in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, postman, mean-stack

I am new to Mean stack. I can't insert any data into mongoDB using post method in nodejs. Here i have added all the relevant nodejs codes.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const { mongoose } = require('./db.js');
var employeeController = require('../node/controller/employeeController');


var app = express();        //calling express
app.use(bodyParser.json());     //congigure express to send JSON data

var urlencoded_body_parser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
});

app.listen( 3000, () =>
    console.log("Server started successfully at Port 3000.")
);


app.use('/employees' , employeeController);
app.use(urlencoded_body_parser);
```

employee.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee',{
    name : String ,
    position :  String ,
    office : String,
    salery : Number
})

module.exports = { Employee };
```

employeeController.js

```
   const express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

var { Employee } = require('../model/employee');

router.post('/', (req,res) => {
    var emp = new Employee({
        name : req.body.name,
        position : req.body.position,
        office : req.body.office,
        salary : req.body.salary
    });
    emp.save((err,doc) =>{
        if (!err){
            res.send(doc);
            console.log(doc);
        } else {
            console.log("Operation Failed : " + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
        }
    })
});

router.put('/:id', (req,res)=> {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
        return res.status(400).send('No record with the given Id ${req.params.id}');
    }

    var emp = {
        name : String ,
        position :  String ,
        office : String,
        salery : Number
    };

    Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set : emp },(err,docs) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.send(docs);
        } else {
            console.log('Error in Updating the Employee details' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2))
        }
    });
});


module.exports = route
```

when i use postman to insert data it inserts only _id and _v to the db. none of my JSON data.  [Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18SVS.png)

Comment: Your `req.body.name` and other `req.body.*` parameters are `undefined` so first make sure that `req.body` contains the body params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is looks like you send only raw text to your server.
To solve this issue you need to specify that your content type is `application/json`.

In postman it might be look like this:
[image]